# How to connect nodes via shortest path along network lines with GRASS v.net modules?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, network, shortest-path

**My goal:**

I would like to connect several nodes via the shortest path along a network --> The red nodes in the next image should be connected along the shortest path of the yellow lines.
[image: Nodes (red) to be connected via the network (yellow)]
**My approach:**

I have tried different v.net modules, such as v.net.steiner directly on the nodes and the network file --> This doesn't seem like the shortest way along the lines to connect the nodes.
[image: Connection generated with v.net.steiner]
[image: Connection generated with v.net.steiner --> not the shortest path]

**My tried solutions:**

- v.clean (snap) to close possible small gaps in the topology
- add length per line segment via field calculator and use this as a 'weight' in v.net modules
- use other v.net modules (e.g., v.allpairs, v.net.path)

**My impression:**

I think all modules consider the shortest path from line intersection to line intersection in the general direction to the next node. As a consequence, nodes are connected via short line segments that might not result in the overall shortest path (see 3rd image).

**My question:**

Which module/approach would connect the nodes via the overall shortest path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found an answer myself.

The problem seems to be the topology of my network file. If I apply *v.clean* (snap) followed by *v.clean* (break or bpol), the nodes can be connected via *v.net.steiner* or *v.net.allpairs* as intended. Before, I didn't apply *v.clean* (break or bpol) after *v.clean* (snap).

The only disadvantage of this solution is the long processing time for cleaning the topology of the entire network file (especially for *v.clean* (snap)).

A little unclear to me is the difference in [*v.clean*](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/v.clean.html) break and bpol, and whether [*v.net.steiner*](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.net.steiner.html) is the optimal module to create the shortest path in this case.

[image: Nodes (red) connected via v.net.steiner (yellow) along network (blue)]

---

### Update

I think the difference between the tool parameters *bpol* and *break* in *v.clean* is the following:

- *break* creates a new segment at each line intersection (one line belongs to one segment only) 
  --> higher feature count (figure 1)
- *bpol* creates polygons from the lines (one line can belong to several neighboring polygons) 
  --> lower feature count (figure 2)

[image: Figure 1 - v.clean break]
[image: Figure 2 - v.clean bpol]

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution! If you are some doubts about the modules that you reported above, maybe the best would be asking a new separate question for attracting more potential answers.